# postgres array : update multiple non contiguous array indices in one query

Tags: arrays, postgresql

Consider a table temp1

```
create temporary table temp1 (
id integer,
days integer[]
);

insert into temp1 values (1, '{}');
```

And another table temp2

```
create temporary table temp2(
id integer
);

insert into temp2 values (2);
insert into temp2 values (5);
insert into temp2 values (6);
```

I want to use temp2 id values as indices of the days array of temp1. i.e. I want to update

days[index] =  99 where index is the id value from temp2. I want to accomplish this in single query or if not possible, the most optimal way.

Here is what I am trying and it updates only one index and not all. Is it possible to update multiple indices of the array ? I understand it can be done using a loop but just was hoping if more optimized solution is possible ?

```
update temp1
set days[temp2.id] = 99
from temp2;

select * from temp1;

 id |    days    
----+------------
  1 | [2:2]={99}
(1 row)
```

Comment: ... but there is no index `2` in the empty array in `temp1`. So what do you expect the result to be? `{0,99}`? i.e. left-fill with zeroes? (BTW, in general I think arrays are overused; it's not clear why you're using arrays in this schema in the first place.)

Comment: I only need those indices to be populated. So the output I expect is {null,99,null,null,99,99}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: Don't use arrays for this. Really. Just because you can doesn't mean you should.

---

PostgreSQL's arrays are really not designed for in-place modification; they're data values, not dynamic data structures. I don't think what you're trying to do makes much sense, and suggest you re-evaluate your schema now before you dig yourself into a deeper hole.

You can't just construct a single null-padded array value from temp2 and do a slice-update because that'll overwrite values in `days` with nulls. There is no "update only non-null array elements" operator.

So we have to do this by decomposing the array into a set, modifying it, recomposing it into an array.

To solve that what I'm doing is:

- Taking all rows from `temp2` and adding the associated value, to produce (index, value) pairs
- Doing a `generate_series` over the range from 1 to the highest index on temp2 and doing a left join on it, so there's one row for each index position
- Left joining all that on the unnested original array and coalesceing away nulls
- ... then doing an `array_agg` ordered by index to reconstruct the array.

With a more realistic/useful starting array state:

```
create temporary table temp1 (
id integer primary key,
days integer[]
);

insert into temp1 values (1, '{42,42,42}');
```

### Development step 1: index/value pairs

First associate values with each index:

```
select id, 99 from temp2;
```

### Development step 2: add nulls for missing indexes

then join on `generate_series` to add entries for missing indexes:

```
SELECT gs.i, temp2values.newval
FROM (
    SELECT id AS newvalindex, 99 as newval FROM temp2
  ) temp2values 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT i FROM generate_series(1, (select max(id) from temp2)) i
  ) gs 
  ON (temp2values.newvalindex = gs.i);
```

### Development step 3: merge the original array values in

then join *that* on the unnested original array. You can use `UNNEST ... WITH ORDINALITY` for this in PostgreSQL 9.4, but I'm guessing you're not running that yet so I'll show the old approach with `row_number`. Note the use of a full outer join and the change to the outer bound of the generate_series to handle the case where the original values array is longer than the highest index in the new values list:

```
SELECT gs.i, coalesce(temp2values.newval, originals.val) AS val
FROM (
    SELECT id AS newvalindex, 99 as newval FROM temp2
  ) temp2values
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT i FROM generate_series(1, (select greatest(max(temp2.id), array_length(days,1)) from temp2, temp1 group by temp1.id)) i
  ) gs
  ON (temp2values.newvalindex = gs.i)
  FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT row_number() OVER () AS index, val
    FROM temp1, LATERAL unnest(days) val
    WHERE temp1.id = 1
  ) originals
  ON (originals.index = gs.i)
ORDER BY gs.i;
```

This produces something like:

```
regress=> \e
 i |    val 
---+----------
 1 |       42
 2 |       99
 3 |       42
 4 |         
 5 |       99
 6 |       99
(6 rows)
```

### Development step 4: Produce the desired new array value

so now we just need to turn it back into an array by removing the `ORDER BY` clause at the end and using `array_agg`:

```
SELECT array_agg(coalesce(temp2values.newval, originals.val) ORDER BY gs.i)
FROM (
    SELECT id AS newvalindex, 99 as newval FROM temp2
  ) temp2values
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT i FROM generate_series(1, (select greatest(max(temp2.id), array_length(days,1)) from temp2, temp1 group by temp1.id)) i
  ) gs
  ON (temp2values.newvalindex = gs.i)
  FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT row_number() OVER () AS index, val
    FROM temp1, LATERAL unnest(days) val
    WHERE temp1.id = 1
  ) originals
  ON (originals.index = gs.i);
```

with a result like:

```
       array_agg       
-----------------------
 {42,99,42,NULL,99,99}
(1 row)
```

### Final query: Use it in an `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE temp1
SET days = newdays
FROM (
        SELECT array_agg(coalesce(temp2values.newval, originals.val) ORDER BY gs.i)
        FROM (
            SELECT id AS newvalindex, 99 as newval FROM temp2
          ) temp2values 
          RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT i FROM generate_series(1, (select greatest(max(temp2.id), array_length(days,1)) from temp2, temp1 group by temp1.id)) i
          ) gs 
          ON (temp2values.newvalindex = gs.i)
          FULL OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT row_number() OVER () AS index, val
            FROM temp1, LATERAL unnest(days) val
            WHERE temp1.id = 1
          ) originals
          ON (originals.index = gs.i)
) calc_new_days(newdays)
WHERE temp1.id = 1;
```

Note, however, that **this only works for a single entry in `temp1.id`,and I've specified `temp1.id` twice in the query: once inside the query to generate the new array value, and once in the `update` predicate.

To avoid that, you'd need a key in `temp2` that references `temp1.id` and you'd need to make some changes to allow the generated padding rows to have the correct id value.

I hope this convinces you that you should probably not be using arrays for what you're doing, because it's *horrible*.